# Convert string into enum during @RequestBody deserialization with a HashMap

Tags: java, spring-mvc, enums, hashmap

I'm having a hard time converting a String into an ENUM in @RequestBody annotated method argument. The Map in the argument somehow has a value of a string even though the value is an Enum type. What do I do to automatically convert the String into the correct type?

Enum

```
public enum Fruit{
    ORANGE,
    APPLE,
    PEAR
}
```

Request:

```
{"123":"ORANGE", "456":"APPLE"}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateFruit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateFruit(@RequestBody Map<String, Fruit> fruitMap){
    // Fruit comes in as a String. So the map is a Map<String, String>
    // do stuff....
}
```

Comment: Well what value comes in as String there? If it is `ORANGE`, `APPLE` like so, then I guess it should work automatically. If case is different, then you would have to do some work.

Comment: What Spring version are you using? It works fine for me on 4.

Comment: I am on spring 3.1.0.RELEASE. and I am using the right enums values.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you upgrade to Spring 3.2+ which does what you want out of the box with the Jackson 2 library (you'll need to import that dependency as well).

If you can't, you can create a custom class

```
class FruitMap extends HashMap<String, Fruit> {} // or some other Map implementation
```

and use that as your parameter type

```
public void updateFruit(@RequestBody FruitMap fruitMap){
```

Don't forget to set your `content-type` header in the request.